# Alert/Confirm button must stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I enter values on the fields (Section, Title of Documents, etc.) and then clicking submit, it shows a pop up dialog box that it has been sent to the database (There are no errors in my php file for the database-displayQM.php). When i click 'Ok,' it redirects to another page that is on the form action of my main php file. How can it stay on the same page and not redirect?

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css" />
    <title>Quality Management System</title>
    <script language = "javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            confirm("Sent to Database!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <img src = "logo.png">
    <body bgcolor = "#191970">
    <p>
        <font color= #FFF8DC>
            <font face = "Verdana">
                <font size = 6>
                    <b> QMS - Quality Management System</b>
                </font>
                <p>
                    <ul id="menu-bar">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="QualityManual.php">Quality Manual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="QualityProcedures.php">Quality Procedures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="WorkInstructions.php">Work Instructions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Support Documents</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="QualityForms.php">Quality Forms</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Reference.php">Reference</a></li>
                                <li><a href="JobDescription.php">Job Description</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <p>
                        <font size = 6 font face = "Verdana" font color= #FFF8DC> Quality Manual</font>
                        <p>
                            <br>
                            <form action = "displayQM.php" method = "post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
                                <table BORDER="2" style="border:5px solid white;border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2" bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana">Section</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana">Title of Documents</th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana">Document No.</th>
                                        <th colspan="5" bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana">Revision Status </th>
                                        <th rowspan="2" bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana">Number <br>of Pages</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana"><center>0</center></td>
                                        <td bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana"><center>1</td>
                                        <td bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana"><center>2</td>
                                        <td bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana"><center>3</td>
                                        <td bgcolor = "#D3D3D3"><font face = "Verdana"><center>4</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMsection_1" size = "9" placeholder="(Enter Section)" value = "" maxlength = "5" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMtitleofdocuments_1" size = "30" placeholder="(Enter Title of Document)" value = "" maxlength = "100" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMdocumentno_1" size = "14" placeholder="(Enter Document No.)" value = "" maxlength = "100" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMrevisionstatus0_1" size = "7" value = "" maxlength = "10" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMrevisionstatus1_1" size = "7" value = "" maxlength = "10" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMrevisionstatus2_1" size = "7" value = "" maxlength = "10" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMrevisionstatus3_1" size = "7" value = "" maxlength = "10" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMrevisionstatus4_1" size = "7" value = "" maxlength = "10" align = "right" tabindex ="1"></td>
                                        <td><input type = "text" name = "QMnumofpages_1" size = "10" value = "" maxlength = "3" align = "right" tabindex ="1" ></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                                </p>
                            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use AJAX  , its better.

Comment: is the script where the input gets stored displayQM.php? If so, what do you have displayQM.php

Comment: @VictorLuna displayQM.php is for the connection to the database, and to post the inputted values of my form to the database. In my previous trials, if the inputted values were successfully sent to the database upon clicking the 'submit' button on the main php file, it will redirect to displayQM.php and displaying 'Sent to Database!' on the page. This time I want the confirmation/alert button to just be on the same page as my main php file.

Comment: the one thing I can think of is to only use php to have a redirect from the displayQM.php. You can have 'header("url: page.php");' at the end of displayQM.php file

Answer (score 0):

keep action value empty as

```
<form action = "" ....
```

Comment: I have two php files in this, one for my main php file and the other for the connection to the database. If I remove the value in the form action " ", the inputted values would not be shown in the database.